# iMacro if else statement javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, imacros

I'm faced a problem in my code. It keep repeat execute the first if statement but didn't check for the second if statement. Which it keep on show the message "I'm double from lose". Currently making a script, let say the image1 matches the screen image, it will proceed to stuff1, else if image2 matches with screen image proceed to stuff2.

```
   if(iimPlay("Lose.iim")>0) 
   {
    iimPlay("Double.iim");
   alert("I'm double from lose");

   }
   else if (iimPlay("Win.iim")>0)
   {
      iimPlay("Reset.iim");
   alert("I'm reset from Win");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that after the first `if` condition evaluates to be `true`, all the following `else if` statements in the chain don't execute. Rewrite the second condition w/o `else`:

```
if (iimPlay("Win.iim") > 0)
{
   iimPlay("Reset.iim");
   alert("I'm reset from Win");
}
```

That way, even if the first `if` condition is `true` it'll try to evaluate the second `if` condition.